# change time format in table list

Tags: javascript, php, date

```html
<thead> <th><b>Period Product</b></th> <thead>
```

and the value like this

```html
<td><?= $recentlist->date_from; ?> - <?= $recentlist->date_to; ?></td>
```

now the resulst is
2019-08-01 - 2019-08-31

---

how I changed it with javascript to 2019/Aug/01 - 2019/Aug/31

I'm sorry I have never done this before, thank you if you are willing to help me

Comment: Why format it with JavaScript if you print it with PHP? Use [`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

Use php function **date_format**

```php
<td><?= date_format($recentlist->date_from, "Y-M-d"); ?> - <?= date_format($recentlist->date_to, "Y-M-d"); ?></td>
```

---

You will need to use something called `date_format`

The syntax is as follows:

```php
date_format( $date_object, $format );
```

See the official doc on the function here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php

And for all available formattings:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp

Comment: If an entire answer is TLDR, why bother posting it?